# pointplot not showing line when palette is set

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

when I use any palette in `sns.pointplot()` the line is not showing no matter if I set `join=True`, or choose any linestyle, the points have palette colors, but they are not connected. Should it be like that? Or is there other parameter I can set to connect the points? The line can be one color.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One option might be to draw two pointplots, one using the palette and showing the errorbars and points, the other showing the connecting line (without palette).

```
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
tips = sns.load_dataset("tips")
#make one plot for the line without points and errorbars
ax = sns.pointplot(x="day", y="tip", data=tips, markers="",
                   join=True, ci=None, color="k")
#make one plot for the points without the connecting line
ax = sns.pointplot(x="day", y="tip", data=tips, 
                   palette=sns.color_palette())

plt.show()
```

[image]

The drawback clearly is that seaborn completely ignores the `zorder` and draws the line on top of the dots. Therefore one would need to play around with the zorder externally to have a somehow appealing result:

```
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
tips = sns.load_dataset("tips")
#make one plot for the line without points and errorbars
ax = sns.pointplot(x="day", y="tip", data=tips, markers="",
                   join=True, ci=None, color="k")
#make one plot for the points without the connecting line
ax = sns.pointplot(x="day", y="tip", data=tips, 
                   palette=sns.color_palette())

ax.lines[0].set_zorder(2)
for l  in ax.lines[1:]:
    l.set_zorder(5)
for c  in ax.collections:
    c.set_zorder(3)

plt.show()
```

[image]